# Avoid getting old branches

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

Suppose I have TFS setting like this :

```
DefaultCollection
--CollectionA
----Branches
------1.0.0
------1.0.1
----Trunk
--CollectionB
----Branches
------2.0.0
------2.0.1
----Trunk
--CollectionC
----Branches
------1.0.0
------1.0.1
----Trunk
```

Now I always end up right clicking on the DefaultCollection and say GetLatest and it gets me the whole universe. Most of the time, I need only the Trunks of the 3 collections to get latest.

Is there a way in TFS to blacklist old branches like 1.0.0, 2.0.0 so that I don't get latest when I right click on DefaultCollection?

I should still be able to get latest version of the branches when I right click on the individual branches.

Comment: I urge you to read the [ALM Rangers' Version Control Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/). Your style of branching causes this and many other problems.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". If your title was something like "C# WebRequest..." then be aware that "WebRequest" is part of .NET, not part of C#. Same with every other .NET class that follows "C#" or "VB.NET" in a title.

Comment: Thanks John, but the style which we are following is working very well for us. And we branch only when needed. Above diagram was just an illustration...

Comment: Have you read the guide I posted? TFS treats branches as first-class objects, which makes the best branching styles for TFS different from the best branching styles for other source control systems. Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unusual to have the entire team project mapped into a single workspace. Instead, create a workspace that is meant to map only the latest branches. Use *that* workspace to do your "get latest" and other day to day operations.

Comment: We read the guide when we were laying out our TFS structure. We didn't want to go too complex on our branching strategy. And we had no branches in the beginning. We only created them when we started requiring them. And I like your idea. Probably we should map the workspace only to the branches/trunk we need.

Comment: I suggest you read the guide in the light of your experiences with the branching structure you've decided on. In particular, read about how "Track Changeset" and "Track Workitem" work. I'm curious how your branch paths will evolve from the structure you've shown. That looks like an old school "branch per version" setup, where "branch per concurrent activity and label per version" usually works better.

Comment: John, I would not say 'unusual'. It really depends on the size and complexity of the project.

Comment: @GiulioVian: in my experience, it's unusual to have a team project small enough that a single workspace makes sense.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I appreciate your comments and I am willing to go through the guide at some later point in time. At the moment, the workspace mapping with cloaking unneeded branches work fine for me !